# Template string in value attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I want to keep parameters in URL to keep state after refresh a page and I try to implement something like:

```
<Link to="/estimates/edit/${estimateId}?name=review-information"></Link>
```

But it seems no working, any idea how to pass 'complex' string to `to` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<Link to={`/estimates/edit/${estimateId}?name=review-information`}></Link>
```